# Display Zoom on MAC

Tags: mac, display, zoom

Is it possible to change how much the screen is zoomed in **without** the need to change the resolution?

I want something like on Windows:

[image]

Comment: Please amend your question with more details about your hardware and software. Specifically, (1) What macOS version are you running, (2) What is the model and year of your Mac, and (3) What display(s) are you using with your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

A comparable dialog also exists in macOS:

- Choose **Apple** - **System Preferences** - **Displays**.
  [image: Displays - Scaled]
  Keep in mind that scaled resolutions can affect performance.

Comment: For me, it doesn't show the larger text - default -more space.